# Expansion of factorial of a natural number as a summation

Tags: summation, factorial

Factorial of any natural number $n$ can be expanded as a summation

> $$n!=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i\times i!)$$$$=1+1\times 1!+2\times 2!+3\times 3!+4\times 4!+..............+(n-1)\times (n-1)!$$
>    $\forall \ \ n\in N$

Although, I have derived & proved, by using induction, the above expansion of the factorial [here](https://www.academia.edu/8430657/HCRs_Series_Expansion_of_any_factorial_as_the_summation_of_finite_terms_) on the basis of the generalized formula derived by me still I have doubt if there is another method to derive/prove.

Is there is an easier mathematical derivation/proof of the above expansion of factorial?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $k\cdot k! = ((k+1)-1)\cdot k! = (k+1)! - k!$

Comment: Induction seems to work too.  $1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\,i!=n!+(n)n!=(n+1)!$

Comment: Also, this is the basis of a representation of natural numbers due, I think, to Cantor: the "places" in the number (like the 1s, 10s, 100s, etc. places in decimal) are the 1s, 2s, 6s, 24s, etc.; the "digits" for the 1s place are 0 and 1; for the 2s place, they're 0, 1, 2; for the $k$-factorial place, they're $0, \ldots, k$. To make this work, it's essential that when you reach $4\cdot 24 + 3 \cdot 6 + 2 \cdot 2 + 1$, you can add 1 to get to to $1 \cdot 120$, and so on. In short..Cantor probably proved this statement as a lemma some time ago. :)

Comment: I believe we are close to see this problem been posted for the $100$th time.

Comment: This is related to the [Factorial Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). Induction is probably the easiest way to prove it.

Answer (score 7):

For fun, we give a combinatorial argument.

The numbers $1$ to $n$ are seated in a row, in that order. We count, in two different ways, the number of ways to reseat these numbers so that *at least one* number moves. The usual way of counting gives $n!-1$.

Maybe $1$ is the smallest number that moved. There are $n-1$ ways to choose its new position. For each of these ways, there are $(n-1)!$ ways to choose the positions of the remaining $n-1$ numbers, for a total of $(n-1)(n-1)!$.

Maybe $2$ is the smallest number that moved. There are then $n-2$ ways to choose where $2$ goes. For each of these ways there are $(n-2)!$ ways to seat the rest of the numbers, for a total of $(n-2)(n-2)!$.

Maybe $3$ is the smallest number that moved. There are then $n-3$ ways to choose where it goes. For each of these ways there are $(n-3)!$ ways to seat the rest of the numbers, for a total of $(n-3)(n-3)!$.

And so on. Finally, maybe $n-1$ was the smallest number that moved. It only had $1$ place to go, and the remaining number $n$ also has $1$, here called $1$, place to go.

That gives (backwards) a total of $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\cdot k!$ permutations in which at least one number moves.